# How to find an index in an array Structs

Tags: blockchain, solidity

I am new to solidity, I decided to write a simple code, but for some reason I get an error when I try to run the searchIndex function it gives out an error I tried to find a solution on the internet but I could not find it.
Simple code, but can't solve the problem, can't find the solution.
'''
pragma solidity ^0.8.12;
contract Main {

```
struct Shop {
    string name;
    uint id;
}

Shop[] Shops;

uint GlobalId;

constructor() {
    createNewShop("First");
    createNewShop("Second");
    createNewShop("Third");
}

function createNewShop(string memory _name) public {
    Shops.push(Shop(_name, GlobalId));
    GlobalId++;
}

function searchIndex(uint _id) public view returns(uint) {
    uint index;
    for(uint i = 0; i <= Shops.length; i++) {
        if(Shops[i].id == _id) {
            index = Shops[i].id; //Why does it give out an error
        }
    }
    return(index);
}
```

}
'''

Comment: I found the solution by gut feeling, I had to put a 'break' after the index in the loop.
` function searchIndex(uint _id) public view returns(uint) {
    uint index;
    for(uint i = 0; i <= Shops.length; i++) {
        if(Shops[i].id == _id) {
            index = Shops[i].id; //Why does it give out an error
            break;
        }
    }
    return(index);`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)", "[mre]" and their linked pages. Edit your question and add your comment to it as if it'd been there initially. We don't know what the error was, so we can't help you. Also read "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)".